# Ruby Date Gem Invalid Date

Tags: ruby, date, parsing, hash, argument-error

So I am iterating through a hash where one of the key/values is {date: => 'MM/DD/YYYY'}

When I iterate through, I am using the date gem to find out what day of the week that each date is, (0-6).

To get a day of the week for the index I am currently at as an integer so i can compare it to another integer, the idea is to check if the day of the week of the index is the same as the day of the week i am searching for.

To get that int I run the following commands:

```
d = Date.parse(hash[i].values[2])
day_of_the_week = d.cwday
```

When i do this on its own for just a cherry-picked date this works fine, but I am iterating through the hash, what i get is:

```
search.rb:25:in `parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

for the particular date '9/13/17'.

Is there something wrong with '9/13/17'? Why does this actually work for other days (it starts at '9/5/17') and then get randomly stuck at this day?

And as I was writing this, I did a little digging and found exactly what index it was:

```
d = Date.parse(hash[4224].values[2])
day_of_the_week = d.cwday
```

Gives me the same error, I am completely baffled, what is going on? Also its not the lack of MM in 9/etc because every other month is the same way.

EDIT: The result should be 2, September 12th 2017 was a Tuesday.

Comment: can you output exactly what `hash[4224].values[2]` gives? `Date.parse('9/13/17')` works exactly as expected. `Date.parse('9/13/17').to_s; #=> "09/13/2017"`

Comment: hash[4224].values[2] gives: '9/13/2017'

Comment: and why would you expect that to give you "09/12/2017" as a date? Also to be sure you're passing a string, check `hash[4224].values[2].class` and see if it indeed is a string object.

Comment: hash[4224].values[2].class yields string. Also, printing out the actual index [4224] for more context i get: {:parking_lot=>"Lot 1", :capacity=>68, :date=>"9/13/2017", :time=>"12:00AM", :spots_taken=>6}. Do you kinda see what im struggling with? I dont understand why this is happening at all. It seems to make zero sense

Comment: The overall goal of the code is to look at this hash, that has (made up) data about named parking lots from the past year, each hour of each day has a number of spots taken out of its capacity. I am iterating through the entire hash, with a specific day and time, when i find a match, i am taking the average number of spots taken on that specific day of the week and time for each week of the dataset. The idea is I input whatever time/day it is now and give a guess of how many spots that there could be open. So when i parse through, i get to 9/13/2017 and it throws this error. So weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the format of your date, use

```
Date.strptime('9/13/2017', '%m/%e/%Y').
```

Comment: Yep, just found this and bam, no conflicts. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I found that using:

```
d = Date.strptime(hash[i].values[2], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Does creates a date object of the current index better than:

```
d = Date.parse(hash[i].values[2].to_s)
```

Replacing that did the trick.